# How to bring all replicas on a SQL availability group to an earlier state / point in time?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, restore, availability-groups

I have a SQL Always on availability group, with 4 replicas. One of them is the primary. Lets say someone accidentally drops a table on the primary. This transaction would go to all of the secondary replicas.

Now if I want to restore the state of the entire group to before the table was dropped, what would be the correct (time efficient) sequence of steps to take? Assuming I have all the full and transaction backup files needed.

From my current understanding, restoring a back up on the primary alone would cause a data conflict (or corruption issues) on the secondary replicas - so I have to suspend data movement and drop the availability databases on the secondary before I restore a back up, then re-seed the databases from scratch on the secondary replicas. Is this is the best approach? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is the correct approach.

**From my current understanding, restoring a back up on the primary alone would cause a data conflict (or corruption issues) on the secondary replicas**

Unless you remove the database from the Availability Group, you will not be able to restore the same database on the primary node.

On a side note:
If it is just dropping one table (depending on the size of the table compared to the database size) I might consider restoring the backup with a different name and recreate that table in the primary. There are many ways to do that which is not the scope of this question.

Comment: "restoring the backup with a different name and recreate that table in the primary" - meaning, after the backup is restored to a new database, I run a cross database query to re-create the table? or would it be better to generate a "table create script" which includes the data and then running then on the original database?

Comment: You can use the import/export tool. Create the table with the same definition and then import the data.